# SCP selectively from directory and subdirectory

Tags: linux, scp

I don't know if this possible but I wanted to check with all UNIX geeks here.

We have a directory structure as follows:

```
Subject_11
 -subdir01
 -subdir02
 -subdir03
 -subdir04
```

Now I want to `scp` only `subdir03` to another location but want to transfer it with the directory structure as it is. For eg, the destination should contain `subdir03` under `Subject_11` but all other subdir's should not be transferred.

Destination dir structure should look like as follows:

```
Subject_11
 -subdir03
```

Is this possible with `scp` command? If yes, how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: if the `/Subject_11` directory is existing on the target server, you can do it by running `scp -r /Subject_11/subdir03 remote_server:/Subject_11`. You need to have all the existing directory tree available on the target node, excluding the last directory in the tree (if you have that one as well, it doesn't hurt)

Comment: I dont have directory existing on the target server. I guess i will need to create it and then transfer data.

Answer (score 2):

`scp` does not have this functionality. However, this can be done using `rsync` with the `-R` option. [Here is the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

`rsync -aR Subject_11/subdir03 user@remote_server:/path/to/destination`

Comment: You can have `rsync` work via `ssh` with the `-e ssh` argument.

Comment: @DopeGhoti - Is that necessary? I just found this line from wikipedia: `By default, rsync uses the remote-shell program SSH for its communication`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync#Uses

Comment: I've run into some cantankerous machines recently that don't exhibit this behavior, so I've just gotten into the habit of specifying `-e ssh`

Comment: @DopeGhoti what does `rsync` use if not `ssh` and why is whatever else it uses bad?